# Use FFmpeg to crop a video to square format in Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am currently working on an app that is supposed to crop a 16:9 video into a 1:1 video. However I dont get the code working. If possible the software should convert the inputed video as fast as possible. The resolution can vary between 480x480 and 720x720.

If I could choose the postion of the crop frame it would be perfect.

The error I get:

```
E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [Ljava.lang.String;@f0c91b8
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/user/0/com.android.grafika/files/ffmpeg, -i /storage/emulated/0/Alphacrypt1.mp4 -vf crop=640:256:0:400 -threads 5 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 /storage/emulated/0/YourCroppedMovie.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:215)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:174)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:129)
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10)
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:213)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:174) 
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:129) 
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10) 
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38) 
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The code I am using:

```
final String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i /storage/emulated/0/Alphacrypt1.mp4 -vf crop=640:256:0:400 -threads 5 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 /storage/emulated/0/YourCroppedMovie.mp4"};

    try {
        final FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully converted!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail!"+ message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {

    }
```

Thank you for your help.

**SOLUTION:**

1. I did not add the "Load Binary" part, which is necessary to run the
   FFmpeg library (http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/).
2. The command needs to be splitted using `.split(" ");` as already told by *printfmyname*
3. For now I use -vf crop=1080:1080:0:0 to crop the video to a square. (Without messing up the ratio)

Answer (score 1):

I think the exec command that been called from Ffmpeg expect a string array with all parameters tokenized. Try changing

```
final String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i /storage/emulated/0/Alphacrypt1.mp4 -vf crop=640:256:0:400 -threads 5 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 /storage/emulated/0/YourCroppedMovie.mp4"};
```

To

```
final String[] cmd = "-i /storage/emulated/0/Alphacrypt1.mp4 -vf crop=640:256:0:400 -threads 5 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 /storage/emulated/0/YourCroppedMovie.mp4".split(" ");
```

Comment: Thanks dude that worked out. I also had to add the Load Binary part to use the library. (Check http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/). Furthermore do you know how I now could crop the video to a square format?

Comment: Do you want to make it a square video by cropping( you will look part of the video) or by padding the video to make it square?. Also Do you know the exact source video dimension or aspect ratio?

Comment: Well I am not sure if I understand what exactly you mean by cropping or padding. Please explain a bit more in detail. And yes I know everything necessary about the source video, since I record it before. For now I used the method of -vf crop=1080:1080:0:0 which seems to work out pretty well. If there is a faster method I would be happy if you could tell me about it. And maybe also about an alternative one. Thanks :)